# Finder like coloured labels

Tags: cocoa, finder

OS X Finder has this nice feature to colour-label files. I'm thinking of using a similar feature in my app (that is: use this in an NSTableView/NSOutlineView, not looking to highlight items in Finder from my app). Is this ability somehow available through any of the default user interface classes or would it require a custom implementation?

I have experimented with setting NSTextFieldBezelStyle to NSTextFieldRoundedBezel but this seems to kill the ability to draw a background colour and also defaults to a grey border.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the NSURL NSURLLabelColorKey, which is one of the attributes you can set for a URL.  You can set these values with setResourceValues:error:

After Edit: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question.  I think the easiest way is to use a view based table and put a borderless label inside an NSBox of the custom type.  You can give the box rounded corners and a background color with no border, and that looks just like the finder label.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to implement this in an `NSBrowser` or `NSOutlineView`, not how to label files in the Finder.

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm looking for an implementation in an NSTableView, NSOutlineView...

Answer (score 0):

Download the Apple SourceView sample app. It's an NSOutlineView that uses a custom NSTextFieldCell for the drawing; tweak that to draw your custom colors.